# Under windows, is there any way to force the stack to use large pages?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, huge-pages

Is there a way to compile a windows program so it will allocate the stack using SEC_LARGE_PAGES or the equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Large pages do not behave like regular pages, and the kernel expects the stack to contain regular pages.

Comment: I suppose the stack has a pretty high TLB cache hit ratio because a significant amount of activity on the stack is with small objects at one end.